# Problemas con Vectores ,Maps y Pairs en c++;

Tags: c++

Hola buenas me gustaría saber como acceder al contenido de este template en c++;

```
vector<map<pair<int, int>, double>> m_deltaQ;
```

con dos numeros int por ejemplo 3 , 4 como sacar el valor double

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta exactamente? Quiere completar el template con varios números de variables `int` o quiere saber como añadir elementos a un objeto con esta firma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

personalmente preferiría usar una clase para ese tipo de diseño, sin embargo, si deseas acceder deberías tener el cuenta que lo primero que debes identificar es el mapa donde se encuentra el dato que buscas. El siguiente código te devuelve el valor, teniendo en cuenta que solo hay un mapa y es el primero del vector.

```
vector<map<pair<int, int>, double>> m_deltaQ;
map<pair<int, int>, double> mapa;   
pair<int, int> pareja(3,4); 

mapa.insert(pair<pair<int,int>,double>(pareja,10.5));   
m_deltaQ.push_back(mapa);

cout<< m_deltaQ[0].find(pair<int, int>(3, 4))->second <<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, sería aconsejable crear alias de tipos para dar un significado semántico a cada estructura de datos:

```
using key = std::pair<int, int>;
using delta = std::map<key, double>;
using delta_pack = std::vector<delta>;
```

Con estos alias, podrías insertar datos así:

```
delta_pack m_deltaQ;
//                       delta
//                  vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
m_deltaQ.push_back({{{3, 4}, 10.5}});
//                   ^^^^^^
//                     key
```

Para acceder al `double` de `delta`:

```
std::cout << m_deltaQ[0][{3, 4}]; // Muestra 10.5
```

El problema del ejemplo anterior es que si el elemento `{3, 4}` no existiera, se crearía con valor `0.0`, si quieres evitar crear elementos accidentalmente debes evitar el operador de indizado (`[]`) de `std::map`:

```
const delta &d = m_deltaQ[0];
const delta::const_iterator k = d.find({3, 4});

if (k != d.end())
    std::cout << k->second; // Muestra 10.5
```